# Returning a variable that has to be updated from a function, not returning?

Tags: php

There is ALOT of code, but most of it is irrelevant, so i will just post a snippet

```
$error_message = "";

function died($error) // if something is incorect, send to given url with error msg
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
    header("Location: http://mydomain.com/post/error.php");
    die();
}
```

This works fine, sends the user away with a error session, which displays the error on the error.php

```
function fetch_post($url, $error_message) {

    $sql      = "SELECT * FROM inserted_posts WHERE name = '$name'";
    $result   = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        $error_message .= $url . " already exists in the database, not added";
        return $error_message;
    }
}
```

This also works fine, checks if the "post" exists in the database, if it does, it adds the error the variable $error_message

```
while ($current <= $to) {

    $dom   = file_get_html($start_url . $current); // page + page number
    $posts = $dom->find('div[class=post] h2 a');

    $i = 0;
    while ($i < 8) {

        if (!empty($posts[$i])) { // check if it found anything in the link

            $post_now = 'http://www.somedomain.org' . $posts[$i]->href; // add exstension and save it

            fetch_post($post_now, &$error_message); // send it to the function
        }

        $i++;
    }

    $current++; // add one to current page number
}
```

This is the main loop, it loops some variables i have, and fetches posts from a exsternal website and sends the URL and the error_message to the function fetch_posts

(I send it along, and i do it by reference couse i asume this is the only way to keep it Global???)

```
if (strlen($error_message > 0)) {
    died($error_message);
}
```

And this is the last snippet right after the loop, it is supposed to send the error msg to the function error if the error msg contains any chars, but it does not detect any chars?

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
strlen($error_message) > 0
```

not

```
strlen($error_message > 0)
```

Also, call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated since 5.3.0 and removed since 5.4.0, so rather than call your function like this:

```
fetch_post($post_now, &$error_message);
```

You'll want to define it like this:

```
function fetch_post($url, &$error_message) {

    $sql      = "SELECT * FROM inserted_posts WHERE name = '$name'";
    $result   = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        $error_message .= $url . " already exists in the database, not added";
        return $error_message;
    }
}
```

Although as you're returning the error message within a loop it would be better to do this:

```
$error_messages = array();

// ... while loop

if ($error = fetch_post($post_now))
{
  $error_messages[] = $error;
}

// ... end while

if (!empty($error_messages)) {
    died($error_messages); // change your function to work with an array
}
```